# Do I need multiple commits in my stored procedure while inserting data in TABLE A and using that data to insert in TABLE B

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, commit, oracle12c

I have a stored procedure in which I am inserting data in `Table T1`. Then based on the inserted data in `Table T1`, I have to insert data in `Table T2` (see below code). My question is - Do I need to use the `commit;` twice (after inserting data in `Table T1` and then again after inserting in `Table T2`) or can I just use it once in the end and I will be join on the data inserted in `Table T1` within that session of procedure while inserting data in `Table T2`?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FOO
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO T1 (ID, NAME, PHONE) 
SELECT ID,
NAME,
PHONE
FROM CUST;

COMMIT; --Do I really need to use this commit here?

INSERT INTO T2 (ID,NAME,CITY)
SELECT C.ID,
C.NAME,
C.CITY
FROM CUST C
JOIN T1 X
ON X.ID = C.ID

COMMIT;

END FOO;
```

Comment: You should not put a commit at all inside a procedure in general, unless it's an Autonomous Transaction. In [Tom Kyte's own words](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1519405621318) : *"I firmly believe transaction control MUST be done at the topmost, invoker level."* So, put all your commits after  invoking your procedure(s).

Comment: Learn about transactions here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/cncpt/introduction-to-oracle-database.html#GUID-ACACFFBC-BCB9-4BA9-A2A3-1B9B2003B3B4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You don't have to put that first commit. The second commit does the job.